# Emacs: incremental search with rgrep and lgrep

Tags: emacs, search

Is there an rgrep and lgrep version of incremental search?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what lgrep is, but I've used these notes for Emacs search (and replace) through the file system:

[http://xahlee.org/emacs/find_replace_inter.html](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/find_replace_inter.html)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean and incremental regex search?  If so `M-x isearch-forward-regexp` will do it.